# Datepick value Javascript into php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to make a tool that can load call history into Excel. 
For this I am using a API. 
This works perfect. however, to get call history, the user have to set a date. I do use Datepick for this.

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $(".datepick2").datepicker({
        'dateFormat': 'd/m/y'
    });

});
</script>
```

as it is in a foreach loop the code is like this:

```
<?php
echo "<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Extension</td>
    <td>Numbers</td>
    <td>Datum</td>
    </tr>";
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {

    echo "<tr>"
    . "<td>" . $value['fname'] . "</td><td>" . $value['lname'] . "</td>"
    . "<td>" . $value['email'] . "</td>"
    . "<td>" . $value['ext'] . "</td>"
    . "<td>";
    foreach ($value['numbers'] as $key2 => $numvalue) {
        echo $numvalue;
    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo("<form action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ">' method='post'> <input type='button' name='tijd' class='datepick2' value='Get call history'></form>");
    echo "</td>";
}
    $tijd = $_POST['tijd'];

                if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                    if ($_POST['tijd']) {
                        echo "hi"; //debugging
                    }
                }
```

as you can see the input is a button and not submit. I have also try to use submit but then it gives me a error when I click on the button.

```
    echo("<form action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ">' method='post'> 
<input type='button' name='tijd' class='datepick2' value='Get call history'></form>");
```

I want the code to pick a date and turn it into a variable in php.

I am not sure what to do with

```
$tijd = $_POST['tijd'];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($tijd) {
        echo "hi"; //debugging
    }
}
```

There must be the problem, however I can't see something

I understand that you might be somewhat confused about the question so I decided to upload a image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrLWH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see ajax anywhere in your code and I'm not sure what do you want to achieve. If you are using a "button" input type, I assume you want to use jQuery to interact with the server side because with "button" you cannot submit a form. I just see some jQuery and php. Php runs on server, can't handle real time action without `$.ajax()`. When you select the date, you must get it's value via javascript. Then you send the value to the server via `jQuery.ajax()`. Something like this:

```
//in the action you select the date:
$("button").click(function(){
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "convert.php",
 data: {date: theDateIPicked},

}).done(function(data){
     //do our stuff we want after we got back the value from the php
   });
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I think I have to use button because PHP won't be able to pick up the date(s) and put them in variable, am I right?
As you see on the image, the user have to set a date and click on get call history, the submit button on the top. this will redirect the user to excel where the XML files will be loaded with the information about the call history.

Comment: @HaltlolXD As I recall, HTML5 has a form element of type date. It's a simple datepicker, like javascript has, but because of it is being a form element, php can store it's value in $_GET/$_POST (depends on form method). I never used it, but I think it is stored as a timestamp. If you can't use it because of some reasons, the above code can help you. EDIT: you must use <!doctype html> for using html5.

Comment: Thanks for the comments & the code:) 
I will check out the html you told me about, I was completly forgot that there was something in html aswell. yet I need to get it unix timestamp, but that is easy to resolve. 
The thing about your code is, that I am totally new in Javascript & Ajax, I struggle alot with those codes

Comment: @HaltlolXD jQuery is much more simple than native Javascript. In javascript the above code would take almost 30 lines.

Comment: The html variant of input type=date is not for IE :(
The company who will use this does only work with Microsoft awh

Comment: I just can't understand these people. We had a lots of projects where the clients used IE9 or older. I just can't understand it. Why? Why do you hurt us, programmers?

Comment: I try to take a look into your JavaScript / AJAX. no other answers yet!